# Summation in excel?

Tags: excel

I need to take the sum from i=1 to n of (a^n * b^(n-i)) where a,b are given constants.  The value for n ranges from 1 to 24, representative of the months since a loan has been made and is now being paid off.

For example, in the first row where n = 1 I've tried

```
=SUM(POWER($B$5, $A$10:A10)*POWER($B$3, A10 - $A$10:A10))
```

where B5 and B3 are the constants a and b and A10:A33 are values for n = 1, ..., 24.  In any case, this formula for my sum works fine for n=1, but for the rest of the table, the formula isn't calculating the sum correctly.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

First: Such formulas have to be array formulas. But your formula seems not to be the exact Excel formula to "sum from i=1 to n of (a^n * b^(n-i))" even as array formula because in my opinion $A$10:A10 is the equivalent to i and not n.

So

```
{=SUM($B$3^$A10*$B$5^($A10-$A$10:$A10))}
```

is the right Excel formula in my opinion.

To create a array formula put the formula into the cell without the curly brackets. Then press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] instead of [Enter] alone. Then the curly brackets should appear automatically.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This array formula (entered with <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>) works:

```
=$B$1^$B$3*SUM($B$2^($B$3-ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&$B$3))))
```

assuming this layout (adjust to suit your layout):

[image]

Note that I have taken the factor a*n out of the summation since it is a constant.

Also note how I hijack the `ROW()` function to generate a sequence of numbers. In an array formula, `ROW(m:n)` returns an array of integers from `m` to `n`; but you have to use `INDIRECT` to hard-code those numbers, otherwise they will change as you add or delete rows. So in the example above, `ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&$B$3))` returns `{1;2;3;4}`. [Reference for this trick.](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx)